# Photodiode circuit to compensate for LED temperature drift

Tags: photodiode, constant-current, stability, color

I'm trying to create a stable light source using 5000K white LEDs. In researching this I've discovered that LEDs drift with temperature by a non-negligible amount. Further research leads me to believe I need to create a circuit using a constant current source and a photodiode/phototransistor that can measure how much the LED is drifting. Before I go ahead and start buying components to whip up some test circuits, I was wondering if anyone knows the following that could save me some time / expense in prototyping:

1. It seems that photodiodes/phototransistors also drift with temperature. Is there something more stable, or is the drift negligible? (see the notes below for how much drift I'm seeing)
2. Is there a known circuit topology for achieving this? I'm not an EE, so maybe this is a common enough circuit and I don't have the right nomenclature for finding it online.

Some notes that may be applicable:

I'm designing a circuit with a color sensor (specifically the AS7341) for detecting color. In testing, while monitoring temperature along with output color there is a correlation between temperature variance and sensed intensity. I could try compensating for this in software, but I figured a hardware implementation will be able to detect the drift more quickly and result in more accurate measurements. I'm seeing a drift of about 0.3% with a temperature change of around 2°F so I need to be able to detect an compensate for at least that much drift.

The temperature sensor is next to the prototype pcb I've designed so the correlation isn't perfect.

The test setup is displaying a pure white background on my laptop screen and having the color sensor continuously report what it senses over time.

[image]

The top plot is the sensed value (raw ADC output), middle is temperature in °F, and the bottom plot is relative humidity.

Comment: The temperature sensitivity of a photodiode may not be significant for this application or could be compensated. See this useful app note: https://ams.com/documents/20143/36005/AmbientLightSensors_AN000169_2-00.pdf/f1f874db-bdde-d69c-2281-f6dd1e011542

Comment: "*I figured a hardware implementation will be able to detect the drift more quickly and result in more accurate measurements.*" You can't have accuracy without a reference which you don't have without calibrated components. At least in software you can present a bunch of colour references and record their outputs under different temperatures and at least you have that. That's all moot though...your photosensor doesn't even have an analog output for you to use in a hardware compensation scheme.

Comment: @DKNguyen could you elaborate? I might be misreading what you said, but FYI the AS7341 isn't what I'd be using to compensate for the LED thermal drift. I figured the final scheme would have something like an extra LED pointed directly at a photodiode, creating a direct feedback loop between the LED's output and it's measured intensity. The AS7341 would just be viewing the reflected image being lit from additional LED's on board. Make sense?

Comment: It doesn't really change that whatever sensor you use in the feedback loop would need to be calibrated itself. And if you're just going to use a bunch of uncalibrated photodiodes you might as well just use the the AS7341 since it's already there. What is even the point of the AS7341, then if it's going to view the LEDs but there is a separate LED-photodiode system controlling all the LEDs?

Comment: And also, photodiodes don't come with sufficient colour filtering to differentiate colours in your application which means you either need to get glass colour filters for each photodiode, or isolate each colour LED in a dark chamber with each photodiode. The first is very expensive and the second defeats the purpose since the LED you're monitoring is operating under different conditions than the LEDs whose output you care about. It also assumes the LED you're monitoring is identical to all the LEDs whose output you care about.

Comment: @DKNguyen The AS7341 will be calibrated by the user at the start of the "session" (it will probably end up being calibrated by a "white standard" that I need to choose to set the LED's maximum intensity). The separate photodiode would then need to maintain the brightness found at calibration for the remainder of the session. The AS7341 isn't viewing the LED's directly, it's viewing a "color" being lit by the LED's. Also I am indeed willing to assume that all of the other LED's illuminating the "color" are identical to the one being monitored.

Comment: You're still better off just using two AS7341s, one for the object being lit and the other for the LEDs and going with digital calibration. Even if you went with individual photodiodes and colour filters you're still better off with digital calibration. I think you might also have issues with the white of emitted light itself drifting with temperature, not just the intensity.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think you're misunderstanding the setup. The AS7341 is looking at a color placed below. Around the sensor are LEDs also facing the color below. The light reflected off the color transmits back into the AS7341. (almost like this https://www.xrite.com/-/media/modules/weblog/archive/0-45-diagram.png). If the LED's dim or brighten over time, the AS7341 just sees this as a darker or lighter color. It is unaware that the light source isn't stable. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JesseBuesking I eventually understood what you meant. See my edited comment.

Comment: I keep bringing up colour filters or using the AS7341 to examine the emitted white light.

Comment: @DKNguyen I was about to say that the AS7341 would make quite an expensive intensity detector :D You're saying thermal drift will have a significant impact on color temperature as well? I was thinking the intensity would be the primary concern, but again I have yet to prototype this and prove if it would be or if both intensity and color temperature are of concern...

Comment: How much is the AS7341? On Digikey it is only $16. Cheaper than good single photodiode. And the glass colour filters alone is $50+ per colour. And is brightness even that important? Isn't it the ratios between the colour channels that determine the colour?

Comment: @DKNguyen I'm not understanding why you think I'd need a glass color filter? Assuming LED brightness is the issue, wouldn't a simple photodiode be enough to monitor change in brightness of just the LEDs being used to illuminate the scene? Say a ALS-PT19-315C/L177/TR8 or SFH 3310?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143182/discussion-between-dknguyen-and-jessebuesking).